Why did Prophet Velen say "something is wrong" when he saw the Xenedar
In World of Warcraft Legion, in the cinematic "Battle for Argus" (from the quest "Into the Night", I think), Prophet Velen says "Something is wrong" when he sees the Xenedar. Why?
